# Portable executable file analysing using c#

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

C/C++ has the set of predefined structures and constants corresponding to an exe-header and so on. Do exist some analogical standard namespaces, classes in C# special for analyzing of portable executable files? Or is it only a prerogative of unmanaged unsafe more native languages?

Comment: C# is perfectly capable of reading binary files. Nothing at all to stop you doing this.

Comment: David, it's exactly what I did before, but I think maybe I try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Well, you could always try a websearch.

Comment: Of course, I did, but could not find the answer.

Comment: You need to find a better search engine. I typed `C# pe file` into Google and got some useful hits. Which search engine are you using?

Comment: Google. Oh, really "C# pe file" works, it seems I use too specific request form. I think it's not a reason to remove the question, isn't it? Maybe it can be userful for people having the same mindset.

Comment: @SerG: I presume pInvoke has all the structures you will need to analyze, no need to reinvent anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exists an managed library called PeNet which is available as open source and as a NuGet package, too. You can access and change nearly all structures in the PE header with this library. 
[PeNet GitHub](https://github.com/secana/PeNet)

Disclaimer: I'm the main author of the library

Answer (score 4):

There's not much built-in to the language (if anything), but there's lots of examples out there, such as

- https://web.archive.org/web/20160312145447/http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=572
- https://web.archive.org/web/20150826092221/http://sergeyakopov.com/2010/11/reading-pe-format-using-data-marshaling-in-net/

Comment: Both of these links are dead

Answer (score 0):

An interesting library which is published for a number of languages including c#:

https://formats.kaitai.io/microsoft_pe/csharp.html

It uses another Kaitai's class named "Kaitai Struct", which is another interesting and more general class for reading binary files.